# My string name is repeating along loop?

Tags: java, string, ascii

**QUESTION**: print the string by removing the PRIME ASCII CHARACTERS.

Here is print Code chart-> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart

Clearly, question says if the ASCII numbers are prime that means you'd have to remove the character. It means If i give input..

**Input**

```
4
MEHTA
Mehta
HELLO
hello
```

**OUTPUT must be**

```
MEHTA
Mht
HELL
hllo
```

Okay, finally i hope you understand this question above .. So as far as i tried this codes:

```
package lesson.practice;

import java.util.*;

public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your number:");
        int num=in.nextInt();
        String name = null;

        System.out.println("Enter name");
        for(int i=0; i<=num; i++){

            name=in.nextLine();
        }

        String str1=name.replace(new String(Character.toChars(97)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(101)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(103)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(107)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(107)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(113)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(117)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(119)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(67)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(71)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(73)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(79)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(81)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(83)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(87)), "").
                replace(new String(Character.toChars(89)), "");

        System.out.println("PRIME ASCII ARE REMOVED:");
        for(int i=1; i<=num; i++){
            System.out.println(str1);
        }
    }
}
```

But as i run my program, it repeats the String .. HAve a look into output

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter your number:
4
Enter name
Mehta
MEHTA
HELLO
Hello
PRIME ASCII ARE REMOVED:
Hllo
Hllo
Hllo
Hllo
```

Comment: You are overriding your string variable 'name' everytime you are reading input. You should creat an array of size `num` and store the strings in it. Or use an `List` which can grow dynamically. And you should use an algorithm to check if the ascii value is prime, instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Thanks... But i guess it still possible without creating an array

Comment: Not if you want to read as many strings as the user wants. But your assignment looks like one string is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are overwriting your `name` and `str1` variables in the loops your output is the result of the last input. To save all inputs and then convert them you have to do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number:");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine(); // so we get rid of the enter key after the number was pressed

    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String[] names = new String[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        String name = in.nextLine();
        String str1 = name.replace(new String(Character.toChars(97)), "").replace(new String(Character.toChars(101)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(103)), "").replace(new String(Character.toChars(107)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(107)), "").replace(new String(Character.toChars(113)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(117)), "").replace(new String(Character.toChars(119)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(67)), "").replace(new String(Character.toChars(71)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(73)), "").replace(new String(Character.toChars(79)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(81)), "").replace(new String(Character.toChars(83)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(87)), "").replace(new String(Character.toChars(89)), "");

        names[i] = str1;

    }

    System.out.println("PRIME ASCII ARE REMOVED:");
    for (String removedName : names) {
        System.out.println(removedName);
    }
}
```

This method will get name input, remove the prime characters and save the result in the names array. Afterwards we print the array to stdout.

Comment: Onething would like to know from you... why do you write `in.nextInt();` ?? .. when i remove it shows me output with less number of input ..why?

Comment: Please can you tell me?

Comment: You had it in your code as well, or do you mean `in.nextLine();` ? Because if we dont have that then the first name will be the remaining part of the first line where the user entered the number! I.e. it will be empty (because `nextLine()` does not return `\n`)

Answer (score 0):

your code should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number:");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String[] result = new String[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        String name = in.nextLine();
        String str1 = name.replace(new String(Character.toChars(97)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(101)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(103)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(107)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(107)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(113)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(117)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(119)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(67)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(71)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(73)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(79)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(81)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(83)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(87)), "")
                .replace(new String(Character.toChars(89)), "");

        result[i] = str1;

    }

    System.out.println("PRIME ASCII ARE REMOVED:");
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }

    in.close();
}
```

Comment: It's throwing an `Exception...`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution to your problem.This is what I have coded.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class ASC{
public static boolean chkprim(int no){
    for(int i=2;i<no;i++){
        if(no%i==0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    int n;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter no. of values");
    n=sc.nextInt();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int i=1;
    String arr[]=new String[n];
    while(i<=n){
        System.out.println("Enter the word:-");
        String st=br.readLine();
        arr[i-1]=st;
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        String str=arr[i];
        for(int j=0;j<str.length();j++){
            int num=(int)str.charAt(j);
            if(chkprim(num)==false)
            System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Change the condition in your for loop to `i <= Math.sqrt(no)` to improve the performance significantly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!It worked wonders.But tell me one thing,did my code execute properly?